# Convert month=Jan or month=jan strings in .bib files into integer

Tags: bibtex, external-files, conversion, tools

[Tame the Beast](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) suggests to use plain integers over strings in the `month` key.

I have mixed `month` formats in my .bib file and want a unique solution.
Which tools can convert the different strings like "jan" and "Jan" (wrapped in 0 to 2 pairs of `{}`) to `1`?

Comment: If there is nothing ready to use, I will write a brute force `sed` script. I thought I was not the first with this problem...

Comment: probably it's been done before  but the sed script wouldn't be much longer than the question:-)

Comment: I started, but it is not so easy, as it initially seemed. I have to check, that the line starts somewhere with `Month` sometimes the months are wrapped in one or two `{}` brackets too and cases are mixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given this not very valid bib file

```
aaa.bib
year= jan
journal="jan of feb of dec"
month="1"
month = "Jan"
month=  "{{jan}}"
month=  {{jan}}
month=  {jan}
month=  "2"
month=  {Jan}
author="Jan de Groote"
```

The following command

```
 sed -e 's/\(^ *month\) *= *["{]{*jan}*[}"]/\1 = "1"/i' aaa.bib
```

outputs

```
aaa
year= jan
journal="jan of feb of dec"
month="1"
month = "1"
month = "1"
month = "1"
month = "1"
month=  "2"
month = "1"
author="me"
```

which looks like the right thing, so you just want 11 more similar lines and it should be done (save a copy of your file first!!)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have put this all together in a bash script. Perhaps others need it too: https://github.com/jonasstein/month_str2int Are you fine with that?

Comment: @JonasStein glad it worked:-)

Answer (score 3):

Quoting ttb:

> It’s better having a numerical value, or an abbreviation

Quoting biblatex manual:

> This must be an integer, not an ordinal or a string.

In JabRef, we nevertheless decided to go for abbreviations, which did not cause trouble on our side:

```
@Article{,
  month = jun,
}
```

To achieve that, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> or Quality -> Cleanup Entries... Then, following dialog appears:

[image: clean up entries]

If the contents of "Run field formatter" look different, just press "Recommended for BibTeX".

With File -> "Switch to biblatex mode", one can switch to biblatex mode and then have "Recommended for biblatex".

[image: clean up defaults for biblatex]

Comment: It doesn't matter if its a literal or a number, if you use the DATE field  (YYYY-MM-DD) of biblatex it overrides the month field. JabRef is also able to convert from year+month field to date